# flask jwt extended protect only specified request methods

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt-extended

I have several general purpose `routes` in my `API`:

```
...
/api/general/user_types
/api/general/dlc_types
...
```

I want to have the `GET` method opened for all users without `JWT token`, but the `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods only accessible when the `JWT token` is included in the request.

The problem is that all these methods are allowed on the same route and I serve a different function based on the request method - `GET = read`, `POST = create`, `PUT = update`, `DELETE = delete`.

Any way to do this without separating the `GET` method into a separate route?

Here is how my routes are declared:

```
@general_api.route("/user_types", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])
@jwt_required()
def user_types_crud():
    instance = ConstantsRoutes(UserTypes, "type")
    return crud_routes(request, instance)
```

The `ConstantsRoute` builds a `CRUD` class for the `UserTypes` table (`SQLAlchemy` model), and the `crud_routes` function takes a look at the `request.method` and returns the proper `method` (`create`|`read`|`update`|`delete`).

Comment: Hi Dimitar I edited the code to add some typing and pass the params as in the default decorator. If that helps you, please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry I was off the clock at work didnt really get a notification. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a build in `decorator` provided by the library. But if using a slightly extended version of the build in `decorator` is an option for you, you could define one as followed:

```
from typing import Any
from typing import Union
from typing import Sequence

from functools import wraps
from flask import request, current_app
from flask_jwt_extended import verify_jwt_in_request

LocationType = Union[str, Sequence, None]


def jwt_required_for_methods(
    protected_methods: list[str] = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    optional: bool = False,
    fresh: bool = False,
    refresh: bool = False,
    locations: LocationType = None,
    verify_type: bool = True
) -> Any:

    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            if request.method in protected_methods:
                verify_jwt_in_request(
                    optional, fresh, refresh,
                    locations, verify_type
                )
            return current_app.ensure_sync(fn)(*args, **kwargs)

        return decorator

    return wrapper
```

This way the `JWT token` is verified only if the request method is in the `list` passed as an argument. Protect your route with this `decorator`, where needed:

```
@general_api.route("/user_types", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])
@jwt_required_for_methods(['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def user_types_crud():
    instance = ConstantsRoutes(UserTypes, "type")
    return crud_routes(request, instance)
```

Hope i could help!